# Adding a class to an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem adding the class "hide" back to the #artist after the setTimeout function.  I don't know what the problem is.

```
$('#user_type span').click(function(){
    value = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#user_type input[name="user_type"]').val(value);
    $('#user_type').addClass('hide');
    $('#welcome').fadeIn(500).removeClass('hide');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#artist').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');
        $('#artist_name').focus();
    },1500);
    $('#artist').change(function(){
        $('#artist').addClass('hide');
        $('#pass').fadeIn(500).removeClass('hide');
        $('#artist_pass').focus();
    })
});
```

The above code effectively adds the class to the html element, but it is not being removed from the viewport.

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Can you post the CSS for "hide?" Also, if you're just trying to hide the element (and that's all the hide CSS class does) you can use jQuery's hide():  `$('#artist').show();`  or  `$('#artist').hide();`

Comment: You got `$('#artist').change` what is `#artist`? A form element or something else?

Comment: Sorry guys.  I'm not really a programmer.  I'll try to ask better questions in the future.
And for your information, hide() worked liked a charm! TY